# How do I add legends in a groupby line plot in plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to add legend for each line in a grouped line plot in plotly but I cannot find the relevant documentation.
Here is the code without the legends (code from the official documentation https://plot.ly/r/group-by/).

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatter',
  x = mtcars$hp,
  y = mtcars$qsec,
  text = paste("Make: ", rownames(mtcars),
               "<br>hp: ", mtcars$hp,
               "<br>qsec: ", mtcars$qsec,
               "<br>Cyl: ", mtcars$cyl),
  hoverinfo = 'text',
  mode = 'markers',
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = 'groupby',
      groups = mtcars$cyl,
      styles = list(
        list(target = 4, value = list(line =list(color = 'blue'))),
        list(target = 6, value = list(line =list(color = 'red'))),
        list(target = 8, value = list(line =list(color = 'black')))
      )
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a layout command at the bottom will work `layout(showlegend = TRUE)`.  This can work by being piped in using the `library(dplyr)` package as shown here:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

p <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatter',
  x = mtcars$hp,
  y = mtcars$qsec,
  text = paste("Make: ", rownames(mtcars),
               "<br>hp: ", mtcars$hp,
               "<br>qsec: ", mtcars$qsec,
               "<br>Cyl: ", mtcars$cyl),
  hoverinfo = 'text',
  mode = 'markers',
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = 'groupby',
      groups = mtcars$cyl,
      styles = list(
        list(target = 4, value = list(line =list(color = 'blue'))),
        list(target = 6, value = list(line =list(color = 'red'))),
        list(target = 8, value = list(line =list(color = 'black')))
      )
      )
    )
  ) %>%
layout(showlegend = TRUE)
```